# Is there a way to calculate the enclosed volume of two unit balls centered at $(0,0,0)$ and $(1,1,1)$ using a triple integral?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, analysis, volume

> Let $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^3$ be the subset $$\Omega = B((0,0,0),1) \cap B((1,1,1),1)$$ where $B(x,r)$ stands for the ball centered in $x$ with radius $r$.
>
> I was looking for an easy way to calculate the volume with a triple integral.

Also because the exercise asks, after this, to calculate $$\int_{\Omega} (x+2y+z) dV$$ and $$\int_{\partial \Omega} (x+2y+z) d\Sigma$$

> Since this was an exercise from a test that does not last long, there must be some shortcut that I'm missing here.

Does someone have some ideas? Thanks!

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do using a triple integral?

Comment: Do you mean a volume integral ?

Comment: Sorry, I edited it now. I forgot to write that the first thing I'm asked to do is to calculate the volume of $\Omega$.

Comment: I am not entirely sure but volume integral could be reduced to a surface integral like $$\iint_S (x^2/2, y^2, z^2/2).\hat{n} dS$$ this I think should be zero by divergence theorem or stokes' theorem. I remember doing something like this in electrodynamics class in highschool. If the charge generating electrical field wasn't inside a surface net flux was zero or something like that.

Comment: You could try to use a 3D rotation transform to rotate (1,1,1) to $(\sqrt{3},0,0)$ such as using transform $\begin{pmatrix}\frac1{\sqrt{3}}&\frac1{\sqrt{3}}&\frac1{\sqrt{3}}\\0&1&-1\\\frac2{\sqrt{6}}&-\frac1{\sqrt{6}}&-\frac1{\sqrt{6}}\end{pmatrix}$

Comment: @Sonal_sqrt the integral can't be zero, the volume must be positive, just look at a figure of $\Omega$.

Comment: @ZhaohuiDu exactly what I did but the calculations remain pretty long. Also, how can I deduce the other two integral that I'm ask to calculate from the volume integral? Is there some trick?

Comment: The subset is a union of two spherical caps. You can compute the volume for these directly without integrals, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_cap. For the second part, note that both $\Omega$ and $\partial \Omega$ are symmetric in $x,y,z$. This means instead of integrating $x+2y+z$ you could also integrate for example $4x$ or $\frac{4}{3}(x+y+z)$, which should simplify your integration somewhat.

Comment: Thanks but, isn't the figure only symmetric rispect to $z$? So we should have $\int_{\Omega}x+2y+z = \int_{\Omega}x+2y$ right? And then the integral $\int_{\Omega}x$ isn't just the "medium" $x$ multiplyed for the volume? And the same for $y$?

Comment: Then the barycenter of the $x$'s is at $\frac{1}{2}$ so we would have $\int_{\Omega} x = \frac{1}{2} | \Omega|$ and the same for $y$

Comment: @quarague - The $xyz$-symmetry indeed simplifies the integrals to be performed.

Comment: @ZhaohuiDu - A 3d transformation does help simplify the integrands in the other two integrals and then they can be worked out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Due to the perfect symmetry of the two-ball configuration around the axis (1,1,1), these three integrals can be carried out relatively straightforwardly.

Such symmetry is obvious for the simple volume integral,

$$I_1=\int_{\Omega} dV$$

For the other two integrals, we observe that

$$\int_{\Omega} xdV = \int_{\Omega} ydV = \int_{\Omega} zdV$$

and rewrite them in symmetric forms explicitly

$$I_2=\int_{\Omega} (x+2y+z) dV=\frac{4}{3}\int_{\Omega} (x+y+z) dV$$

$$I_3=\int_{\partial \Omega} (x+2y+z) d\Sigma=\frac{4}{3}\int_{\partial\Omega} (x+y+z) d\Sigma$$

Observe further that $x+y+z = a$ is a plane intersecting all three axes at $a$ and  $a$ is proportional to the altitude $h$ from the origin to the plane. In fact, $a = \sqrt{3}h$. Therefore, $x+y+z$ in the integrands can be conveniently replaced by $\sqrt{3}h$, i.e.

$$I_2=\frac{4}{3}\int_{\Omega} \sqrt{3}h dV$$
$$I_3=\frac{4}{3}\int_{\partial\Omega} \sqrt{3}h d\Sigma$$

Now rotate the $z$-axis to be align with the direction (1,1,1) and reparametrize the two balls as,

$$x^2+y^2+z^2=1$$
$$x^2+y^2+(z-\sqrt{3})^2=1$$

All three integrals can then be performed readily along the $z$-axis, albeit in two regions corresponding to the two spherical caps. In the rotated ordinates, the altitude is simply  $h=z$, and the three integrals become,

$$I_1 = \int_{\sqrt{3}-1}^{\sqrt{3}/2} \pi[1-(z-\sqrt{3})^2]dz + \int_{\sqrt{3}/2}^1 \pi(1-z^2)dz=\pi\left(\frac{4}{3}-\frac{3\sqrt{3}}{4} \right).$$

$$I_2 = \frac{4}{3}\int_{\sqrt{3}-1}^{\sqrt{3}/2} \pi\sqrt{3}z[1-(z-\sqrt{3})^2]dz + \frac{4}{3}\int_{\sqrt{3}/2}^1 \pi\sqrt{3}z(1-z^2)dz=\pi\left(\frac{8}{3}-\frac{3\sqrt{3}}{2} \right).$$

$$I_3 = \frac{4}{3} \int_{\sqrt{3}-1}^{\sqrt{3}/2} 2\pi\sqrt{3}z\sqrt{1-(z-\sqrt{3})^2}dz + \frac{4}{3}\int_{\sqrt{3}/2}^1 2\pi\sqrt{3}z\sqrt{1-z^2}dz=\pi\left(\frac{2\pi}{3}-\sqrt{3} \right).$$

Comment: Thanks, great answer!

Answer (score 2):

You intersect two unit balls whose centers have the distance  $\sqrt{3}$. Therefore you may take $(\sqrt{3},0,0)$ as center of the second ball. The rim of the resulting lens is in the plane $x={\sqrt{3}\over2}$. We therefore obtain the following volume of the intersection:
$${\rm vol}(\Omega)=2\cdot\pi\int_{\sqrt{3}/2}^1(1-x^2)\>dx={16-9\sqrt{3}\over12}\>\pi\ .$$